# Find the force of attraction exerted by a homogenous cone of altitude h and vertex angle $\alpha$ on a point located at vertex.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the force of attraction exerted by a homogenous cone of altitude h and vertex angle $\alpha$ (in axial cross section) on a material point containing unit mass and located at its vertex.

I am picturing a cone with the base on the $z=0$ plane and the point of attraction on the top of the cone. The law of gravitation states

$$F = -\frac{Gm_1 m_2}{r^2}$$

In this case, the $m_1 = 1$ (some unit mass), and $m_2 = dm$ of some mass inside the cone. So the problem can be shown as (in cylindrical coordinates) :

$$\int\int\int_V-\frac{G}{L^2} \ r \ dz \ d\theta \ dr$$
Where $L$ is the length from the $dm$ mass to the vertex point of the cone. Now, for $L$ in terms of $r, \theta, z$ .  A generic point written in cylindrical coordinates $(x,y,z) = (r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta), z)$. The distance between this point and $(0,0,h)$ ie: the vertex is:

$$L = |(0,0,h) - (r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta), z)| = |(-r\cos(\theta), -r\sin(\theta), h-z)| = \sqrt{r^2 + (h-z)^2}$$

Now, for the bounds (a is the radius of the base):

$$\int_{0}^{a(1-\frac{z}{h})}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{h} -\frac{G}{L^2} \ r \ dz \ d\theta \ dr$$

Since $z = (h - \frac{h}{a}r)$ rearranging gets $r = a(1-\frac{z}{h})$ becoming the bound for $r$.

Problem here is that I am suppose to get a vector quantity at the end (something along $-2\pi G(1-\cos(\alpha))z \cdot \vec{u_z}$ ...) How can I setup this problem properly?

Comment: Let me establish a strategy for finding this quantity when w/o uniform density. Suppose the density of your cone $$\mathcal{C}=\Big\{(x,y,z):0\leq z\leq h-\cot(\alpha/2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\Big\}$$ at the point $(x,y,z)$ is $\delta(x,y,z)$. The force of gravity exerted by a small piece of the cone of volume $dV$ located at $(x,y,z)\in \mathcal{C}$ is given by the vector quantity $$\frac{G\cdot 1\cdot \delta(x,y,z) dV}{\|(x,y,z)-(0,0,h)\|^2}\cdot \frac{(x,y,z)-(0,0,h)}{\|(x,y,z)-(0,0,h)\|}$$ Integrating this expression over $\mathcal{C}$ will provide you with your sought after resultant force vector.

Comment: If you knew that $\delta(x,y,z)$ was constant over $\mathcal{C}$ you could also use the fact that the force vector necessarily points towards the center of mass of the cone which is well$-$ known to reside a quarter of the way up from its base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to only consider force in z-direction and

$dF_z = dF \ cos \phi = dF \cdot \cfrac{h-z}{L}$ where $\phi$ is angle between z-axis and segment between vertex and the point in the cone. So your integral should have $(h-z) r $ in the numerator and $L^3$ in the denominator.

Alternatively, for ease of working, I will suggest to use spherical coordinates which is easier here and also place the point unit mass at the origin with the axis of symmetry being z-axis.

The force of attraction between the point mass at $(0, 0, 0)$ and a small mass element $dm$ in the cone will have two components - one along z-axis and one perpendicular to it (along the cross section of the cone). As z-axis is the axis of symmetry and the point mass is on z-axis, the force perpendicular to z-axis will cancel each other out when we consider the whole cross section of the cone.

Using spherical coordinates,

$x = \rho \cos\theta \sin\phi, y = \rho \sin\theta \sin\phi, z = \rho \cos\phi$

$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \rho$

Now at $z = h$, $z = \rho \cos\phi = h \implies \rho = h \sec\phi$

Also, $dF_z = dF \cos\phi = \cfrac{G \ dM \cos\phi}{\rho^2} $

$dM = \sigma \ dV = \sigma \ \rho^2 \sin\phi \ d\rho \  d\phi \ d\theta$

Where $\sigma$ is the mass density of the cone and if $M$ is the mass of the cone,

$\sigma = \cfrac{3 M}{\pi h^3 \tan^2\alpha}$

The integral is,

$\displaystyle |F| = G \cdot \sigma \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\alpha} \int_0^{h \sec\phi} \sin \phi \cos \phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta$

$ \displaystyle = 2 G \ \sigma \ \pi \ h (1 - \cos\alpha)$

And note that $\vec F = |F| \ \hat z$